# Criando Listeners no GridView usando uma List Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou criando um menu com um gridview no flutter.
As ações estão numa List:

```
List<Map> actions = [
{"description": "Cadastro", "icon": Icons.people, },
{"description": "Alterar Senha", "icon": Icons.security},
{"description": "Contra Cheque", "icon": Icons.attach_money},
{"description": "Histórico de Contribuições", "icon": Icons.print},
{"description": "Sair", "icon": Icons.directions_run, "onTap": logout},]
```

Pretendo colocar as ações ai também, como no caso da ação sair chamando o método logout no onTap. o método:

```
static void logout(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),));}
```

Então, por fim, no builder do gridview eu chamo um método para gerar cada ação:

```
 Widget createGridViewTile(int index) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: actions[index]["onTap"] != null ? actions[index]["onTap"](context) : null,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        iconSize: 70,
        onPressed: () {

        },
        icon: Icon(
          actions[index]["icon"],
          color: widget.primaryColor,
        ),

      ),
      Text(
        actions[index]["description"],
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: widget.primaryColor,
          fontSize: 14,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);}
```

Porém, na linha que cria o onTap está retornando o seguinte erro (se tirar a linha do ontap funciona):

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

> E/flutter (19906): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2334 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.
> E/flutter (19906): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
> E/flutter (19906): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
> E/flutter (19906): #2      _RouteEntry.handlePush. (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2334:18)
> E/flutter (19906): #3      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:398:15)
> E/flutter (19906): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
> E/flutter (19906): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
> E/flutter (19906): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
> E/flutter (19906): #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
> E/flutter (19906): #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
> E/flutter (19906): #9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
> E/flutter (19906): #10     Future._asyncComplete. (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
> E/flutter (19906): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
> E/flutter (19906): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
> E/flutter (19906): #13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
> E/flutter (19906): #14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
> E/flutter (19906): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
> E/flutter (19906): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
> E/flutter (19906):

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nessa linha:

```
onTap: actions[index]["onTap"] != null ? actions[index]["onTap"](context) : null,
```

Existe o elemento `actions[index]["onTap"](context)`.

Como você colocou `(context)` isso não está passando uma função como parâmetro, e sim o retorno dela.

Para corrigir, você poderia tentar colocar diretamente a função, se não fosse pela necessidade do parâmetro `context` que sua função requer e o GestureDetector [não passa](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureTapCallback.html) no `onTap`:

```
onTap: actions[index]["onTap"] != null ? actions[index]["onTap"] : null,
//Precisa do context
```

Para resolver isso, uma das alternativas é criar uma função anônima que chama a sua, por exemplo da seguinte forma:

```
onTap: actions[index]["onTap"] != null ? () => actions[index]["onTap"](context) : null,
```

Uma maior introspectiva sobre o erro pode ser lida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55622474/10746978) (em inglês).

Comment: Entendi o erro! Funcionou perfeitamente agora, obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita, se achar válido, para a pergunta ficar como resolvida e ajudar eventuais buscas no site.